# Spring Boot 2 Device Detection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm upgrading a project from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2.0. I was using device detection and looks like org.springframework.mobile.device was removed.

Are there any alternative ways to detect device types?